# MDB Database and MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, ms-access

I am working for a client who had a website developed and doesn't want the backend changing. Unfortunately he is on windows and used an MDB database D:

That database is on a different server...

I need to be able to access that database from `www.domain2.com`

The database is on `www.domain1.com/Admin/DataBase/DB.mdb`

Accessing it through the URL isn't possible. You have to use the ftp path:

```
ftp.domain1.com/htdocs/Admin/DataBase/DB.mdb
```

What can I do to get around this? I was thinking if it would be possible to make a MySQL database which will be a constant duplicate of the MDB file. Is that possible? I doubt it though.

The other option I thought of was accessing that mdb file. But how, I can't access it through the www, I'd need to use FTP.

Comment: if the customer doesn't want the backend changed away from MDB, then the customer is an idiot. MDB hasn't been a good idea for webserver databases since pretty much forever. If the point is that this allows them easy access to the database, then tell them that there's such a thing as ODBC which allows the exact same access, but without all the performance and security issues inherent to MDB files. As it is, I'm voting to close this.

Comment: Hang on, why am I getting downvoted on forced to close because of my client? I'm trying to find a method to solve this so I reached out for help. What a great community this is.

Comment: In my opinion, this is not a poor question at all. I suggest leaving it open.

Comment: I actually have written a jdbc connector to access mdb-database on IIS server (ASP) so you can access it in local application, its only java 1.4 and does not support prepared statement (it was mostly for fun, so no production code). Search on sourceforge for jddurldbdriver if you are interested to see how it can be done (source code is available in cvs). Stating this however I need to vote to close.

Comment: Basically the trick is to have a php or similar where the database is, you communicate with php, the php communicates with database and return result (xml or json)

Comment: @OllieJones, I judged it as recommend to find a tool, sorry but could not find a way to judge it differently even if it would have been fun to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can't meet this client's needs in a reliable way. The results of this "integration" will probably end up being Worse Than Failure™. If you proceed with this job, please be sure you arrange to bill your client hourly for maintenance. There's no obvious reason for you to take a vow of poverty to support this ill-conceived scheme.

If the Access database (the mdb file) is relatively static, you can write a bunch of application specific code to sync its tables to a real RDMS like MySQL. If you do this in PHP, you'll use the ODBC driver. http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php

The machine on which the php sync program runs will have to have Windows-style CIFS or SMB file-system access (*not, repeat not, FTP access*) to the mdb file. You'll need to make the mdb file available in a network share, for that to work.

This shared-access to mdb setup is a potential source of unreliability. You can mitigate some of that by only reading, and never writing, the mdb file from your php program. You can also allow for recovery by making sure you have solid backups on the mdb file.

If your php sync program, and indeed any program touching the mdb file, can be run in a Windows environment, it will help maintain the mdb file's integrity.

Once you've pulled data from the mdb file using ODBC and put it into an RDMS, you can create your web site normally.

Another alternative: hybrid solution.  Read application data from the mdb file, and read/write web-site data (passwords, sessions, and the like) to the RDMS.

It *may* make sense to try to convince your client to migrate from access to a modestly-sized MS SQL Server database. That's a fairly well-travelled path. If you do that, you can connect your php program directly to SQL Server.

This project sounds like your client saying, "I want to take all my customers to New York City. I have this bicycle. Can you drive it and carry them all?"

Comment: Thanks for that. I think I will have to try and convince the client. Thanks again!